# CakePHP - javascript files do not update when loading

Tags: javascript, cakephp, caching

I am building something using CakePHP 2.5.5. I have a layout where I load multiple javascript files. That works fine. But when I edit 1 of those files and reload the page, nothing changes.

Apparently the javascript files still stay with the old version and dont update to the new version I just edited.

I tried clearing my *tmp->cache* folder in the *App* folder. Yet that doesnt fix it.

Anyone an idea why this happens? I am sure it has something to do with caching or something simulair.

Comment: Try to use different browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with CakePHP and everything to do with your browser's cache.  Clear cache and try again, or try a different browser...etc.

Sometimes I use Ctrl+F5 in Chrome, which supposedly "Reloads your current page, ignoring cached content", but that seems to work 10% of the time for me.